# Why incoming message can't show in the left side of the screen?

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication, xcode8, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I got some error when I send photo message.

[image]

I'm a beginner with swift language. I want to create undergraduate project about chat app.  I need some help to fix this problem. Everything had worked smoothly till now but I am facing a small bug that is when I receive an image then it don't appears on the left side of the screen both incoming and outgoing images appear on the right side of the screen.

```
import UIKit
import JSQMessagesViewController
import MobileCoreServices
import AVKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseAuth
import SDWebImage

class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {
var messages = [JSQMessage]()
var avatarDict = [String: JSQMessagesAvatarImage]()
var messageRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    {
        self.senderId = currentUser.uid

        if currentUser.isAnonymous == true
        {
           self.senderDisplayName = "anonymous"
        } else
        {
            self.senderDisplayName = "\(currentUser.displayName!)"
        }

    }

    observeMessages()
}

func observeUsers(_ id: String)
{
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(id).observe(.value, with: {
        snapshot in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        {
            let avatarUrl = dict["profileUrl"] as! String

            self.setupAvatar(avatarUrl, messageId: id)
        }
    })

}

func setupAvatar(_ url: String, messageId: String)
{
    if url != "" {
        let fileUrl = URL(string: url)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileUrl!)
        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        let userImg = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with: image, diameter: 30)
        self.avatarDict[messageId] = userImg
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

    } else {
        avatarDict[messageId] = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with: UIImage(named: "profileImage"), diameter: 30)
         collectionView.reloadData()
    }

}

func observeMessages() {
    messageRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
       // print(snapshot.value)
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let mediaType = dict["MediaType"] as! String
            let senderId = dict["senderId"] as! String
            let senderName = dict["senderName"] as! String

            self.observeUsers(senderId)                                
            switch mediaType {

            case "TEXT":

                let text = dict["text"] as! String
                self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, text: text))

            case "PHOTO":

                let photo = JSQPhotoMediaItem(image: nil)
                let fileUrl = dict["fileUrl"] as! String
                let downloader = SDWebImageDownloader.shared()
                downloader.downloadImage(with: URL(string: fileUrl)!, options: [], progress: nil, completed: { (image, data, error, finished) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        photo?.image = image
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    })
                })

                self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, media: photo))

                if self.senderId == senderId {
                    photo?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = true
                } else {
                    photo?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = false
                }


            case "VIDEO":

                let fileUrl = dict["fileUrl"] as! String
                let video = URL(string: fileUrl)!
                let videoItem = JSQVideoMediaItem(fileURL: video, isReadyToPlay: true)
                self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, media: videoItem))

                if self.senderId == senderId {
                    videoItem?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = true
                } else {
                    videoItem?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = false
                }

            default:
                print("unknown data type")

            }

            self.collectionView.reloadData()

        }
    })
}

override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {

    let newMessage = messageRef.childByAutoId()
    let messageData = ["text": text, "senderId": senderId, "senderName": senderDisplayName, "MediaType": "TEXT"]
    newMessage.setValue(messageData)
    self.finishSendingMessage()
}

override func didPressAccessoryButton(_ sender: UIButton!) {
    print("didPressAccessoryButton")

    let sheet = UIAlertController(title: "Media Messages", message: "Please select a media", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) { (alert:UIAlertAction) in

    }

    let photoLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (alert: UIAlertAction) in
        self.getMediaFrom(kUTTypeImage)
    }

    let videoLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "Video Library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (alert: UIAlertAction) in
        self.getMediaFrom(kUTTypeMovie)

    }


    sheet.addAction(photoLibrary)
    sheet.addAction(videoLibrary)
    sheet.addAction(cancel)
    self.present(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

func getMediaFrom(_ type: CFString) {
    print(type)
    let mediaPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    mediaPicker.delegate = self
    mediaPicker.mediaTypes = [type as String]
    self.present(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    return messages[indexPath.item]
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
     let bubbleFactory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
    if message.senderId == self.senderId {

        return bubbleFactory!.outgoingMessagesBubbleImage(with: .black)
    } else {

        return bubbleFactory!.incomingMessagesBubbleImage(with: .blue)

    }


}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    return avatarDict[message.senderId]
    //return JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithImage(UIImage(named: "profileImage"), diameter: 30)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("number of item:\(messages.count)")
    return messages.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didTapMessageBubbleAt indexPath: IndexPath!) {
    print("didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath: \(indexPath.item)")
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    if message.isMediaMessage {
        if let mediaItem = message.media as? JSQVideoMediaItem {
            let player = AVPlayer(url: mediaItem.fileURL)
            let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerViewController.player = player
            self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func logoutDidTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    do {
        try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }

    // Create a main storyboard instance
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    // From main storyboard instantiate a View controller
    let LogInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogInVC") as! LogInViewController

    // Get the app delegate
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    // Set LogIn View Controller as root view controller
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = LogInVC
}

func sendMedia(_ picture: UIImage?, video: URL?) {
    print(picture)
    print(FIRStorage.storage().reference())
    if let picture = picture {
        let filePath = "\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser)/\(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)"
        print(filePath)
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture, 0.1)
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
        FIRStorage.storage().reference().child(filePath).put(data!, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error)
            in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            let fileUrl = metadata!.downloadURLs![0].absoluteString

            let newMessage = self.messageRef.childByAutoId()
            let messageData = ["fileUrl": fileUrl, "senderId": self.senderId, "senderName": self.senderDisplayName, "MediaType": "PHOTO"]
            newMessage.setValue(messageData)

        }

    } else if let video = video {
        let filePath = "\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser)/\(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)"
        print(filePath)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: video)
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "video/mp4"
        FIRStorage.storage().reference().child(filePath).put(data!, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error)
            in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            let fileUrl = metadata!.downloadURLs![0].absoluteString

            let newMessage = self.messageRef.childByAutoId()
            let messageData = ["fileUrl": fileUrl, "senderId": self.senderId, "senderName": self.senderDisplayName, "MediaType": "VIDEO"]
            newMessage.setValue(messageData)

        }
    }
}
}

extension ChatViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    print("did finish picking")
    // get the image
    print(info)
    if let picture = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        sendMedia(picture, video: nil)
    }
    else if let video = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL {

        sendMedia(nil, video: video)

    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    collectionView.reloadData()


}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is unclear. What does *a small bug* mean? What bug? On what line is it occurring? Also, that's entirely too much code for us to dig through. Code should be the minimal required to demonstrate the issue. You should include a snippet of your Firebase structure (as text) so we can understand what it looks like. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to understand what is going on in your code ,  as i am looking into your code you are reloading `collectionview` before the `JSQPhotoMediaItem` or `JSQVideoMediaItem` objects are completely configured and added these MediaItem into your message array, so make sure you have completely configured your `JSQPhotoMediaItem` and `JSQVideoMediaItem` objects and only after that you add these object to your message array.

you can add this into your switch case condition

```
    case "PHOTO":

            let photo = JSQPhotoMediaItem(image: nil)
            let fileUrl = dict["fileUrl"] as! String
            let downloader = SDWebImageDownloader.shared()
            downloader.downloadImage(with: URL(string: fileUrl)!, options: [], progress: nil, completed: { (image, data, error, finished) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    photo?.image = image // you have image in your media object
                  if self.senderId == senderId {
                        photo?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = true
                  } else {
                        photo?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = false
                  }
                  // you just configured  media object by using appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing
                  self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, media: photo))
                    // successfully added object into your message array now you should reload collectionview
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                })
            })
        //same goes for your video condition
```

But still i would recommend you to follow each step one by one.

Follow these steps for adding  A `JSQPhotoMediaItem` object

1. make a `JSQPhotoMediaItem` Object like

   ```
   let photoItem = JSQPhotoMediaItem(image: UIImage(named: <your Image Object>))
   ```

   make sure you have downloaded your image from server and successfully have your image object ready to add in the `JSQPhotoMediaItem` Object (as you are downloading it from firebase) first get the image then add it to your `JSQPhotoMediaItem`
2. now you have to tell your message type( outgoing or incoming ) so add `appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing` property to according to you need so this would be in your code

   ```
           if self.senderId == senderId {
               photoItem?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = true
           } else {
               photoItem?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = false
           }
   ```
3. now this is the final step for appending this object to your array

   ```
    self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, media: photoItem))
   ```
4. now reload collectionView as you have successfully configured your media item ( `JSQPhotoMediaItem` )

   ```
     self.collectionView.reloadData()
   ```

same goes for the `JSQVideoMediaItem` objects.